# Items created by AJAX don't respond to jQuery selectors

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have 3 pages: `index.php`, the main page with `update.js`, and `update.php`.

I have a table from `index.php`.  I update the table from a database through AJAX using `update.js` and `update.php`.

The problem is that after the update nothing in the table responds to jQuery selectors.

Here is the code:

**index.php**

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Hello!</title>
  <script src="jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="update.js"></script>
  <style>
    img#pageloading
    {
        display: none;
        position: fixed;
        padding-top: 350px;
        padding-left: 50%;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
<table border="1">
<thead>
<th>first</th>
<th>second</th>
<th>third</th>
</thead>
<?php
for($i=1;$i<=3;$i++)
{
    ?>
    <tr id="row<?=$i;?>">
    <td>first<?=$i;?></td>
    <td>second<?=$i;?></td>
    <td>third<?=$i;?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php
}
?>
<img src="../submit/loading.gif" id="pageloading" />
</table>
<button id="update">update</button>
</body>
</html>
```

**update.js**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#update").click(function(){
        $("img#pageloading").css("display", "inline");
        $("#row1").load("update.php", function () {
            $("img#pageloading").css("display", "none");
        });
    });
    $(".update2").click(function(){
        alert("button update2");
    });
});
```

**update.php**

```
<td>first4</td>
<td>second4</td>
<td><button class="update2">third4</button></td>
```

Comment: if there are better title please write here and i will edit it

Comment: i want to know why someone down vote this question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're loading the elements with ajax, so you'll need delegated event handlers

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#update").click(function(){
        $("img#pageloading").css("display", "inline");
        $("#row1").load("update.php", function () {
            $("img#pageloading").css("display", "none");
        });
    });
    $("#row1").on('click', ".update2", function(){
        alert("buttong update2");
    });
});
```

Comment: oh i suffer alot to see this

Comment: i can't accept the question right now wait and i will accept it

Comment: @robert - Sure, I'll wait !

Comment: someone delete his answer because he think i won't accept his answer